# Error when calling custom function from subroutine in VBA

Tags: vba, function, excel

I have a VBA script for Excel, that has a sub and a custom function.  When I try to call the function from the sub, I get an error upon exiting the function.

> Run-time error '424': Object required

I've tried several different things, but haven't had any luck.  What do I need to do differently to make this work correctly?  Thanks!

```
Public Sub FindValues()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim rn As Range
    Dim RowCount As Integer
    Dim currRow As Integer
    Dim currValue As String
    Dim firstRow As Boolean

    Set sh = Worksheets("MetaData")

    'for each row in Worksheets("MetaData")
    For Each rn In sh.Rows
        currRow = rn.Row

        If (currRow = 1 And firstRow = False) Then
            'Set flag
            firstRow = True
        ElseIf sh.Cells(rn.Row, 1).Value = "" Then
            Exit For
        Else
            'get value from column A
            currValue = sh.Cells(currRow, "A").Value

            'search for value in column B & C in item relations spreadsheet
            Dim FoundVal As Variant
            Set FoundVal = FindItemRelations(currValue)

            MsgBox ("String value found: " & vFound.Value & ", Column: " & vFound.Column)
            MsgBox (FoundVal)
            RowCount = RowCount + 1
        End If        
    Next rn
End Sub

Public Function FindItemRelations(cv As String) As Variant
    Dim found As Boolean
    found = False

    With Worksheets("ItemRelations")

        Set rFoundB = .Columns("B").Find(What:=cv)

        If Not rFoundB Is Nothing Then
            'if value found in B, set value and exit
            FindItemRelations = rFoundB
            found = True

        Else
            'search column C for value
            Set rFoundC = .Columns("C").Find(What:=cv)

            'if value found in C, set value and exit
            FindItemRelations = rFoundC
            found = True
        End If

        If found = False Then
            FindItemRelations = Nothing
            'Exit Function
        End If       
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Run-time error '424':
Object required

Comment: Try changing the return type of function FindItemRelations to Range instead of Variant

Comment: @xidgel
I tried changing the return type like you suggested, and now I receive this error:
Run-time error '91':
Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: In your function FindItemRelations every place where you have "FindItemRelations = …" needs to be changed to "Set FindItemRelations = …"

Comment: @xidgel
I made the change you suggested, and still get the error: **Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set**

Answer (score 0):

I've changed a few bits below to return a Range from FindItemRelations and using Set appropriately. Hope this is what you need.

```
Public Sub FindValues()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim rn As Range
    Dim RowCount As Integer
    Dim currRow As Integer
    Dim currValue As String
    Dim firstRow As Boolean

    Set sh = Worksheets("MetaData")

    'for each row in Worksheets("MetaData")
    For Each rn In sh.Rows
        currRow = rn.Row

        If (currRow = 1 And firstRow = False) Then
            'Set flag
            firstRow = True
        ElseIf sh.Cells(rn.Row, 1).Value = "" Then
            Exit For
        Else
            'get value from column A
            currValue = sh.Cells(currRow, "A").Value

            'search for value in column B & C in item relations spreadsheet
            Dim FoundVal As Variant
            Set FoundVal = FindItemRelations(currValue)

            If Not FoundVal Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox ("String value found: " & FoundVal.Value & ", Column: " & FoundVal.Column)
            End If
            'MsgBox (FoundVal)
            RowCount = RowCount + 1
        End If
    Next rn
End Sub

Public Function FindItemRelations(cv As String) As Range
    Dim found As Boolean
    found = False
    Dim rFoundB, rFoundC As Range


    With Worksheets("ItemRelations")

        Set rFoundB = .Columns("B").Find(What:=cv)

        If Not rFoundB Is Nothing Then
            'if value found in B, set value and exit
            Set FindItemRelations = rFoundB
            found = True

        Else
            'search column C for value
            Set rFoundC = .Columns("C").Find(What:=cv)

            'if value found in C, set value and exit
            Set FindItemRelations = rFoundC
            found = True
        End If

        If found = False Then
            FindItemRelations = Nothing
            'Exit Function
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: With `Set FoundVal = FindItemRelations(currValue)` I get the error: **Run-time error '424': Object required**. When I remove the set and just have `FoundVal = FindItemRelations(currValue)`, I get this error instead: **Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set**

Answer (score 0):

It seems that youre else statement always sets the found var to be true, even if rFoundB and rFoundC could not be found :

```
    Else
        'search column C for value
        Set rFoundC = .Columns("C").Find(What:=cv)

        'if value found in C, set value and exit
        FindItemRelations = rFoundC
        found = True
    End If
```

This should do the trick :

```
 Public Function FindItemRelations(cv As String) As Variant
    Dim found As Boolean
    found = False

    With Worksheets("ItemRelations")
        'search column B for value
        Set rfoundb = .Columns("B").Find(What:=cv)
        'search column C for value
        Set rfoundc = .Columns("C").Find(What:=cv)

        If Not rfoundb Is Nothing Then
            'if value found in B, set value and exit
            FindItemRelations = rfoundb
            found = True
        ElseIf Not rfoundc Is Nothing Then
            'if value found in C, set value and exit
            FindItemRelations = rfoundc
            found = True
        Else
            FindItemRelations = "Not Found"
        End If

    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, I was getting to that case if it wasn't found in B or C, but wanted to get it running first.  I am receiving an error once it reaches
`End Function`.
I've tried changing several things, but cannot get it to run without errors.  I am very new to VBA, so I am still trying to learn the syntax, etc.